# How do I generate a table of IDs which have only one attribute each?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table that looks like this

```
id   attribute
1    a
1    a
2    b
2    a
```

And I want to collect all of the IDs which have ONLY attribute a. So in the example case:

```
id
1
```

My initial thought was to use a `where`, but that would return:

```
id
1
1
2
```

Because 2 also has an "a" attribute in one instance.

P.S. I realize the phrasing of the title is ambiguous; maybe there's a better term than attribute to use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ohh I just saw hive but this is pretty standard sql give it a try.

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    TABLENAME
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT attribute) = 1
```

Having is like a where statement after the `GROUP BY` aggregation has occurred.

Comment: HiveQL has many features in common with more standard SQLs, so I'll need to run it to be sure but I think this may do it for me. I'll mark as answered in a couple minutes if it's successful. Thanks Matt!

Comment: I figured it probably does.  I still need to build out a Hadoop environment to play with : )

Comment: I highly recommend it @Matt. Especially with Tez-on-Hive, it's a pleasure to work with--once you get past some of the quirks of HiveQL.

Answer (score 0):

HiveQL equivalent of SQL using `group by` ,`having` and `distinct`

```
select id from (select id,count(distinct attribute) cnt from table_actual  group by id having cnt='1') tableouter;
```

Comment: but this query is only going to get him id 1 with attribute a.  he wanted to get all ids that only have 1 distinct attribute on it.  So group by is necessary in order to use the HAVING clause.  DISTINCT would be great when you don't want to further limit your results

Comment: Thanks Matt for the headsup, Updated the query to match all the possible results.